# Existence of a linear map to the space of SPD matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

Does there exist a linear map from the set of 24x29 Matrices to the set of Symmetric Positive definite (SPD) 24x24 Matrices? I understand that matrix multiplication is a linear map but from the matrix to the SPD form, is there some sort of a linear map? Prove or disprove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The codomain does not contain a zero element, so any linear map is undefined at the $24\times29$ zero matrix. No such linear map can exist. More generally, it doesn't make sense to define a linear map to a set that is not closed under vector operations.